# Kotlin - Toggling tooltips

Tags: android, kotlin

This currently works but I am trying to reduce the code by calling it in one method. It hides and shows tooltips that I created. What I am trying to do is put the following into one method.

```
private fun showToolTips() {
    mMarker.showInfoWindow()
    for (tv in mToolTipArrLst) {
        tv.isEnabled = true
        tv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    mToolTipVisibility = true
}

private fun hideToolTips() {
    mMarker.hideInfoWindow()
    for (tv in mToolTipArrLst) {
        tv.isEnabled = false
        tv.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
    mToolTipVisibility = false
}
```

Comment: And where is your problem? You already have a field ``mToolTipVisibility`` that stores the current state...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single method with a boolean to indicate if you show or hide it:

```
fun showOrHide(show: Boolean) {
    if (show) mMarker.showInfoWindow() else mMarker.hideInfoWindow()
    for (tv in mToolTipArrLst) {
        tv.isEnabled = show
        tv.visibility = if (show) View.VISIBLE else View.INVISIBLE
    }
    mToolTipVisibility = show
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified in what way you want to combine those methods (with a parameter or without a parameter for example). But this is what I came up with.

```
   private fun toggleToolTips() {
        if(mToolTipVisibility) 
          mMarker.hideInfoWindow()
        else 
         mMarker.showInfoWindow()

        for (tv in mToolTipArrLst) {
            tv.isEnabled = !tv.isEnabled;

            if (tv.isEnabled)
              tv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            else
              tv.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

        }
        mToolTipVisibility = tv.isEnabled
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private fun fixToolTips(flag: Boolean) {
    if (flag) mMarker.showInfoWindow() else mMarker.hideInfoWindow() 
    for (tv in mToolTipArrLst) {
        tv.isEnabled = flag
        tv.visibility = if (flag) View.VISIBLE else View.INVISIBLE
    }
    mToolTipVisibility = flag
}
```